# How to append pandas data-frame in loop using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am facing some issue when appending data-frame in loop:

I have a dataframe which has following structure:

`df`

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Then I write a code:

```
alpha=[0.10,0.05,0.01]
beta=[0.10]
error_est=[0.10,0.20,0.25]
```

Then I iterate over each combination of `alpha,beta and error_est` over my `df` to create `9` different `df` and I append them together like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
from itertools import product

app_dicti={}
appended_data=[]
for a, b, error in product(alpha,beta,error_est):
    
    z_sum=(st.norm.ppf(1-(a/2))+st.norm.ppf(1-b))**2
    req_samp_size_knw=round(z_sum*((1/error)**2),0)

    t_1_minus_alpha_by_2=st.t.ppf(1-(a/2),req_samp_size_knw)
    t_1_minus_beta=st.t.ppf(1-b,req_samp_size_knw)
    
    t_sum=(t_1_minus_alpha_by_2+t_1_minus_beta)**2
    
    req_samp_size=round(t_sum*((1/error)**2),0)
    
    df['sample_statistics']="alpha="+str(a)+"_"+"beta="+str(b)+"_"+"moe="+str(error)
    
    df['required_sample_size']=req_samp_size

    app_dicti["alpha="+str(a)+"_"+"beta="+str(b)+"_"+"moe="+str(error)]=df



for table_name,table in app_dicti.items():
   # store DataFrame in list
   appended_data.append(table)
  # see pd.concat documentation for more info

df_final = pd.concat(appended_data)
```

But when I check my final dictionary `app_dicti`  it has all the proper keys but every key has same value which is last value of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This code is setting all the rows in the table to the same value:

```
df['sample_statistics']="alpha="+str(a)+"_"+"beta="+str(b)+"_"+"moe="+str(error)
    
df['required_sample_size']=req_samp_size
```

Comment: Yes that is I want. That is ok. But I want 9 different data-frames which is based on `"alpha="+str(a)+"_"+"beta="+str(b)+"_"+"moe="+str(error)`

Comment: so `{key1:df1, key2:df2....}`. Where key is `"alpha="+str(a)+"_"+"beta="+str(b)+"_"+"moe="+str(error)`

Comment: In the loop, print each df when it's created to confirm it's correct. Also print app_dicti to confirm df is getting added. If these are okay, there must be an issue with the final for loop.